# How to get @interface parameter in jersey WriterInterceptor Implementation

Tags: java, annotations, jersey, jax-rs, interceptor

I have an interface, for example

```
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AutoLogged {
    boolean query() default false;
}
```

How can I get `query` parameter in interceptor implementation?

```
@Provider
@AutoLogged
public class AutoLoggedInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {
    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(final WriterInterceptorContext context)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        try {
            final String methodName = this.resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getName();
            BasicAutoLoggedProducer.makeCall(methodName);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        } finally {
            context.proceed();
        }
    }
}
```

I can not find it in context.getPropertyNames. I see annotation `AutoLogged` with getAnnotations method. How to retrieve parameter `query` from interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do

```
AutoLogged annotation = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getAnnotation(AutoLogged.class);
if (annotation != null) {
    boolean query = annotation.query();
}
```

> "and want to set parameter `query`"

Not exactly sure what you mean hear, but if you mean you want to set the value at runtime, I'm not really sure the purpose and not really sure how to do it. Hopefully you men *"get"* instead of *"set"* :-)

Comment: I mean to `set` query when annotate method with @AutoLogged. And to `get` in implementation. Thanks.

Comment: Set for _what_ though? You set it when you annotate something. For instance in your resource method `@AutoLogged(query = true)`. All it is is declarative meta data.  You obtain the meta data and decide what to do based on it.

Comment: Correctly, just badly formulated question.