# Jersey 2 - ContainerRequestFilter get method annotation

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

Im trying to get the Method annotation in ContainerRequestFilter object.

**Controler:**

```
@GET
@RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
public String message() {
    return "Hello, rest12!";
}
```

**ContainerRequestFilter :**

```
@Provider
public class SecurityInterceptor implements  javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter {
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
//Here I need To get the @RolesAllowed("ADMIN") annotation value
}
```

**Application :**

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class ExpertApp extends Application {
private final HashSet<Object> singletons = new LinkedHashSet<Object>();

public ExpertApp() {
    singletons.add(new SecurityInterceptor());
}   

@Override
public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    return singletons;
}

public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    return new HashSet<Class<?>>(Arrays.asList(UserControler.class, SearchController.class));

}
```

}

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<!-- Servlet declaration can be omitted in which case it would be automatically 
    added by Jersey -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

How do I ge the @RolesAllowed("ADMIN") value,

Answer (score 5):

#### *You could*...

Inject into your filter `@Context ResourceInfo`, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30773160/2587435), and get the annotation from the `Method`

```
RolesAllowed annot = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getAnnotation(RolesAllowed.class);
```

### *But*...

Jersey already has a [`RolesAllowedDynamicFeature`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/filter/RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.java) that implements the access control for the annotations `@RolesAllowed`, `@PermitAll` and `@DenyAll`.  You just need to [register the feature with your application](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/security.html#d0e12202)

In `ResourceConfig`

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        super(MyResource.class);
        register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
    }
}
```

In `web.xml`

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.RolesAllowedDynamicFeature
    </param-value>
</init-param>
```

Or in your `Application` subclass, you can add it to your `getSingletons()` or `getClasses()` set. Doesn't make much difference which one. No injections occur, so it would be safe to just instantiate it and add it to the singletons.

<sub>**Note:** The first option can be done in any JAX-RS 2.0 application, while the second is Jersey specific.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Your ContainerRequestFilter is implemented as post-matching filters. It means that the filters would be applied only after a suitable resource method has been selected to process the actual request i.e. after request matching happens.

So, @RolesAllowed("ADMIN") will block the call and your filter will never be called.

To avoid that issue, I create custom annotation; for instance:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyRoles {
    public enum MyRole {
        USER, OFFICER, COMPLIANCE, ADMIN
    }

    MyRole role() default MyRole.USER;

    Class<? extends Throwable> expected() default None.class;

    static class None extends Throwable {

        /**
             * 
             */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    }
}
```

In my webservice, I can annotate the method:

```
@POST
@MyRoles
@Path("/secured")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public String mySecuredMethod() {
    // This method is annotated with @MyRoles
    // The authentication filter will be executed before invoking this
    // method
    return "{message='secured'}";
}
```

And in the filter, I check for the custom annotation:

```
private static final String AUTHORIZATION_PROPERTY = "Authorization";
private static final String AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME = "Basic";
private static final ServerResponse BAD_REQUEST = new ServerResponse("Token invalid or expired", 400, new Headers<Object>());;
private static final ServerResponse ACCESS_DENIED = new ServerResponse("Access denied for this resource", 401, new Headers<Object>());;
private static final ServerResponse ACCESS_FORBIDDEN = new ServerResponse("Nobody can access this resource", 403, new Headers<Object>());;
private static final ServerResponse SERVER_ERROR = new ServerResponse("INTERNAL SERVER ERROR", 500, new Headers<Object>());;

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
    System.err.println("GFA Debug SecurityInterceptor ............ ");
    System.err.println(requestContext.getUriInfo().getRequestUri());

    Method method = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
    System.out.println("GFA DEbug method.getName() " + method.getName());

    System.out.println("GFA DEbug method.isAnnotationPresent(PermitAll.class) = " + method.isAnnotationPresent(PermitAll.class));

    // Access denied for all
    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(DenyAll.class)) {
        requestContext.abortWith(ACCESS_FORBIDDEN);
        return;
    }

    // Access allowed for all
    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(PermitAll.class)) {
        System.out.println("GFA debug permitAll ... bye");
        return;
    }

    // Custom roles
    System.out.println("GFA Debug method.isAnnotationPresent(MyRole.class) = " + method.isAnnotationPresent(MyRoles.class));
    if (!method.isAnnotationPresent(MyRoles.class)) {
        requestContext.abortWith(ACCESS_FORBIDDEN);
        return;
    }

    MyRoles myannotation = method.getAnnotation(MyRoles.class);
    System.out.println("GFA custom role ... " + myannotation.role());

    // Then I check for token and validity of role, etc.
}
```